# how to read a website with some data that is only visible after klicked on it

Tags: web-crawler

on https://www.tutti.ch/de/vi/zuerich/zuerich/kleidung-accessoires/uhren-schmuck/suche-omega-uhren/23546216 there is a link on the right "Nummer anzeigen". I want to get this phone numer - e.g. with php file(...)
how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium. First, you can click the element and after that just get the text of the particular of the new element. Here is the code in python:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url="https://www.tutti.ch/de/vi/zuerich/zuerich/kleidung-accessoires/uhren-schmuck/suche-omega-uhren/23546216")
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_1DKu4']//div[@class='_2dvKr']//a//span")[0]
element.click()
# let the browser load data
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
phone_number = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_133_r").text
print(phone_number)
```